# How can I login to googlesheets using R and an existing JSON key?

Tags: r, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I am trying to upload my csv files to my google drive/sheets.

Working code: a window pop-up, I login into my google account, then code works perfectly, file is uploaded.

```
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)

dff <- drive_upload('dff.csv', type = "spreadsheet")
drive_browse(dff)
```

I want to avoid this step. So I went to my googlesheets API and created from that window a service account with owner permission.

```
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)
sheets_auth(scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
            path  = 'myjson.json')

drive_auth(token = sheets_token())
dff <- drive_upload('dff.csv', type = "spreadsheet")
drive_browse(dff)
```

And this does not work. Moreover, the **drive_browse(dff)** opens a browser window with a message that I have no access to the file.

How can I solve this? Maybe there are other options? Ideally I need this script to run without any logins to google at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service accounts behave like any other normal account - they can own files and have permissions to them. i.e. if you create a file with your personal account and attempt to access it using the service account, without giving the appropriate permissions prior to that, it will result in an error.

I suggest you use the service account for both of your communications to the Sheets and Drive APIs. In order to do that, you should replace `drive_auth(token = sheets_token())` to `drive_auth(service_token='myjson.json')` (in case you are using googledrive library v0.1.3) or `drive_auth(path = 'myjson.json')` for v1.0.0 of the library.

Bear in mind that after creating the files using the service account, if you plan on accessing them from any other account you will have to share them to your account beforehand. You can use the [drive_share()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googledrive/versions/1.0.0/topics/drive_share) function in your R code for that.

Further to that, you can consider the use of [delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority) in case you are using G Suite in your domain. This feature will allow the service account to act as (or "impersonate") another user of the domain. Every action that it performs will be as if the subject of the "impersonation" were executing it, anything permissions related included.

Comment: That argument does not exist for the function:
unused argument (service_token =

Comment: @Arkadiw sorry - the proposed answer is for version v0.1.3 of the googledrive libary. Please see the revised answer (applicable to the latest version of the library - v1.0.0)

Comment: My access is still denied when using path. I am not able to upload a file or browse using drive_browse

Comment: @Arkadiw What sort of error are you getting? Did you enable the Google Drive API in the GCP project that the service account belongs to?

Comment: Yes as I mention when run the code without putting the json path, code sends me to a browser window in which I auth my account and afterwards all commands run smooth, I am able to run any command from both packages.
Once I input the JSON, doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Just gave domain wide delegation. Still not working.

Comment: @Arkadiw that is because previously you were using the client OAuth flow (which manually asks you to authenticate) while you are now using Service accounts that allow you to avoid this manual authentication step. You can read more about the types of authentication [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). When you claim it "doesn't work anymore", when you run the script, does it just execute without printing anything? Or does it print any sort of error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202635/discussion-between-carlesgg97-and-arkadi-w).

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by carlesgg97

Once the file is uploaded, it has to be shared to all users.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googledrive/versions/1.0.0/topics/drive_share